# why SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(null, null, null)) allow

Tags: spring, spring-security

Why is authentication allowed in this filter

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final JwtProvider jwtProvider;
    private final AccountService accountService;

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getServletPath().startsWith("/api/auth")
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

            String accessToken = jwtProvider.parseToken(request);
            //Account account = accountService.read(jwtProvider.getAccountId(accessToken));
            Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(null, null, null);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

SecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final JwtProvider jwtProvider;
    private final AccountService accountService;

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(new CorsConfigurationSource() {
                    @Override
                    public CorsConfiguration getCorsConfiguration(HttpServletRequest request) {
                        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
                        config.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("http://localhost:3000"));
                        config.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
                        config.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
                        config.setExposedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
                        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
                        config.setMaxAge(3600L);
                        return config;
                    }
                }))
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request
                        .requestMatchers("/api/account/**").authenticated()
                        .anyRequest().permitAll())
                .addFilterBefore(new JwtTokenFilter(jwtProvider, accountService), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .formLogin(withDefaults())
                .httpBasic(withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

"api/account"

> request-header :
> Authorization : Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJtaWRhcyIsImFjY291bnRJZCI6MSwiaWF0IjoxNzEwODYwNTQ2LCJleHAiOjE3MTA4NjQxNDZ9.OFzVJKswldMteZ1Eb_7I0-WBFAmSly7GQXPFA0xo860

> response : 200

log

> 2024-03-20T15:29:02.556+09:00 TRACE 30741 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter (8/16)
> 2024-03-20T15:29:02.556+09:00 TRACE 30741 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/login', POST]
> 2024-03-20T15:29:02.556+09:00 TRACE 30741 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter (9/16)
> 2024-03-20T15:29:02.557+09:00 TRACE 30741 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter (10/16)
> 2024-03-20T15:29:02.557+09:00 TRACE 30741 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.a.u.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter : Did not render default logout page since request did not match [Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]]
> 2024-03-20T15:29:02.559+09:00 TRACE 30741 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking BasicAuthenticationFilter (11/16)
> **2024-03-20T15:29:03.069+09:00 TRACE 30741 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Did not process authentication request since failed to find username and password in Basic Authorization header**
> 2024-03-20T15:29:03.069+09:00 TRACE 30741 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (12/16)
> 2024-03-20T15:29:03.069+09:00 TRACE 30741 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : matchingRequestParameterName is required for getMatchingRequest to lookup a value, but not provided
> 2024-03-20T15:29:03.069+09:00 TRACE 30741 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (13/16)
> 2024-03-20T15:29:03.069+09:00 TRACE 30741 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (14/16)
> 2024-03-20T15:29:03.069+09:00 TRACE 30741 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (15/16)
> 2024-03-20T15:29:03.069+09:00 TRACE 30741 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthorizationFilter (16/16)
> 2024-03-20T15:29:03.069+09:00 TRACE 30741 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@2e66d24f]
> 2024-03-20T15:29:03.070+09:00 TRACE 30741 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@2e66d24f] using org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthenticatedAuthorizationManager@5b24b7d2
> 2024-03-20T15:29:03.070+09:00 TRACE 30741 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] **o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Did not set SecurityContextHolder since already authenticated UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=2, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[]]**

I registered in security context with JWT information.
However, I wonder why authentication is allowed even if I enter any information.
Are authentication objects registered in the security context unconditionally allowed?
I think it is correct for the following filters to deny authentication for incorrect authentication objects.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
It seems to be authenticated by calling SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication() directly.
What is the right way

Comment: Is it right to authenticate if the information exists in the database?